# Add context menu item for all tabs of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to add a context menu item to all the tabs. Found [this app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/context-menu).
Sample only adds context menu items to the pages created by app.

1. How can add a context menu item to all the tabs
2. To work with context menu, what should be the ideal solution, an app
   or extension.

Answer (score 0):

When we add context menu in chrome extension it get added for all tabs.

To add a context menu do fellowing

Add permission in manifest

```
"permissions": ["contextMenus"]
```

In background js add this to create context menu:

```
var context = "selection";
var title = "My Context Menu";
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context], "id": "context" + context});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextMenuClickHandler);

function contextMenuClickHandler(info, tab) {
    // do something...
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: The examples from Google Developer are very easy to use/follow. Read more and follow the example, it should not take you more than 15-30 minutes to get a simple example working...with menu item and submenu item. good answer @elegant-user

Comment: @DincaAdrian Thanks!